# query does not include specified function

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run the following query in an MS Access 2010 database:

```
SELECT a.[Level], max(a.dte) AS nextDate, IIf(a.[Type1Date]<a.[Type2Date],"t1","t2") AS Type
FROM (
    select [Level], Type1Date as dte, Type1Date, Type2Date 
    FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber=1
    UNION
    select [Level], Type2Date as dte, Type1Date, Type2Date 
    FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber = 1
)  AS a
GROUP BY a.[Level];
```

However, Access is giving me a dialog box stating:

```
You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified  
expression 'IIf(a.[Type1Date]<a.[Type2Date],"t1","t2")' as part  
of an aggregate function.
```

Can anyone explain what this means and show me how to fix the code so that it returns the fields (Level, nextDate, Type) that I am requesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a group query, you can't include columns in the Select statement, unless they're also either in the Group By statement, or an aggregate.   So you probably want to use:

```
GROUP BY a.[Level], IIf(a.[Type1Date]<a.[Type2Date],"t1","t2")
```